# A opengl texture transparent hack

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, transparent, alpha

I wish to make an opengl universal texture transparent hack for the DxWnd tool  (an open-source program hosted o SourceForge). The hack should work for every program using opengl to render RGBA textures. DxWnd cah hook and redirect all calls from libraries, including opengl32.dll.
I've read and tried to implement all suggestions about making a texture transparent, including enabling GL_BLEND, disabling GL_CULL_FACE and setting glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). In addition, there's a routine that enforces the alpha bits of all texture pixels.
I expected that, once finished, the result should be a semi-transparent scene, but that doesn't happen.
For instance, the following is a 3d scene from gl hexen II:
[image]
and this is the final result, with some textures not transparent and most pixel colors lost:
[image]
Just to demonstrate that DxWnd is able to manipulate color pixels (so that this should not be the cause of the problem) this is the same scene with a filter that recolors every texture:
[image]
What could be the reason of the problem? How should I fix it? Please, be aware that since DxWnd is hooking a generic program, it may easily have to confront with opengl calls that have an opposite purpose!

Comment: For correct rendering of transparent 3d models it is important to render polygons in specific order. First you render polygons that are far from camera, and then polygons that are close to camera.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not generally possible just from hooking onto some other application.

You may be able to force blending to be on. But correct transparent rendering is a fundamentally different task from rendering an opaque scene. Because alpha-blended transparency is based on doing per-triangle blending operations with the background, it only really works if you render everything in a back-to-front order.

But as far as the program is concerned, it thinks it is doing opaque rendering. So it's going to render in the order it sees fit to use. Which for more modern applications is probably front-to-back, to take advantage of early depth testing.

And that's the exact *opposite* order you need to make transparency work. And there's no generic way to control the *order* of rendering just by hooking onto a few OpenGL functions.

Furthermore, applications tend to try to avoid rendering parts of the scene that are obviously not visible. So if the application thinks that a particular room is not visible because the door to that room isn't visible, then the room and its contents won't be rendered. So even if you could get the order of rendering correct, you'd also need to make the program change *what* it renders in order to correctly see through stuff.

It should also be noted that doing alpha blending requires that the fragments being rendered have a useful alpha value. But most fragment computations for opaque surfaces will have an alpha value of 1.0. And thus: no blending. And, unless you're dealing with fixed-function OpenGL rendering, or you're willing to manually patch shaders to add your own alpha uniform values, there's no way to change this from outside of the application.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it's not possible to get a perfect result, but I just hoped it was possible to get something better than the second picture. I got some view about objects normally not visible with glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST), but this is just cheating on the z-order and doesn't use transparency.

Comment: .About "doing alpha blending requires that the fragments being rendered have a useful alpha value", yes, I do that, I can force an value on the alpha channel of each texture pixel.